# How do I unzip a zip file on the chromebook?

Tags: zip, chromebook

I can open some zip files via the file app that is preinstalled on the chromebook, but some zip files just won't open up for me. I don;t understand why, since all the zip files I downloaded a few days ago still allows me to open them, but the zip files I downloaded yesterday will not open for me. I tried online zip openers, and it said that they didn;t have permission. What is the issues?

Comment: Ask the source where you got the files how you may open them. Permission issues indicate they could be passworded.

Answer (score 0):

You might find either of these helpful.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wicked-good-unarchiver/mljpablpddhocfbnokacjggdbmafjnon

Supported archive formats:
7z ar cab cpio crx deb iso jar lha/lzh mtree pax rpm tar warc
Supported compression formats:
bz2/bzip/bzip2 gz/gzip lzma lz4 lzip lzo/lzop uu xz Z zstd

https://www.reddit.com/r/chromeos/comments/9w7l0i/whats_the_best_way_to_unzip_7zip_files/

Solid Explorer from the Play Store or other File Managers should be able to handle the extracting.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.